# How to convert .scc closed caption subtitles into human readable text

Tags: video, streaming, subtitles, closed-captioning, .srt

I'm trying to find a tool or library (possibly an open-source tool) to parse or convert .`scc` closed caption subtitle files to a human readable text, say .`srt` or `xml` or any text formats. Is there a strong tool or library to do that?

Previously, I was trying to use `PyCaption` library in Python. But it fails to parse certain .`scc` files.

Answer (score 1):

[Subtitle Edit](https://www.nikse.dk/SubtitleEdit/) can convert to/from `.scc`, `.srt`, and many other formats. It is [GPLv3](https://github.com/SubtitleEdit/subtitleedit) (and possibly also LGPL licensed). It also has a BSD licensed DLL. The downside is that it is C# code.

Comment: Problem is that there is not a perfect tool. For instance, I had examples that `PyCaption` couldn't parse and SE parsed, and yesterday I had a sample that SE parsed, but for some reasons it concatenates multiple captions together as a single one.

Comment: SE's developer is pretty responsive, or at least was several years ago, if you can get a sample to them. It may be worth investing in MacCaption/CaptionMaker for the paid support.

Comment: yeah they are pretty responsive. No paid support.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [this tool](https://github.com/mantas-done/subtitles). It is scc file conversion is tested on a lot of files and is under active development. If you have any problems, report your file and it will be fixed.

```
php subtitles.phar input.scc output.srt
```